# Can I tell Web Browsers to not cache a specific file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

Can I tell Web Browsers to not cache a specific file ?

eg :

`<audio src="myAudio.wav" cache="false"> </audio>`

If so, how ?

This 
`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />` tells Web Browsers to not cache all files. That is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try adding the current timestamp the file.  Something like: `<audio src="myAudio.wav?12345"> </audio>`

Comment: You should be able to configure your web server to issue the correct headers to prevent caching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your web server serves `myAudio.wav`, set some headers to tell the browser not to cache the file.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: <a paste date>
```

For documentation of the date format, [see this RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) (thanks [cHao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao)).

Alternatively, append a timestamp as a GET paramater, e.g. `myAudio.wav?time=39038392832`.

Comment: `Expires:` should have an HTTP-style date.

Comment: @cHao If that's the case, OP can use a date in the past.

Comment: The current date/time is good enough.  It just can't be `0` and be considered valid.  (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21)

Comment: @cHao I'll update the answer. Advantage of a previous date is it doesn't require being computed (like dumping the current date).